# How to make sonar analysis for C++ work?

Tags: sonarqube

I'm trying to use sonar for static analysis on a c++ code. I've installed sonar and configured my project (it appears on the localhost sonar page, but i do not see any code violation for the respective code). I have the C++ community plugin installed.

My sonar-project.properties looks like this:

```
# required metadata
sonar.projectKey=DiceInvaders
sonar.projectName=Dice Invaders
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

# optional description
sonar.projectDescription=DiceInvaders by CS

# path to source directories (required)
sonar.sources=D:\\DiceInvaders\\Code

# path to test source directories (optional)
#sonar.tests=D:\\DiceInvaders\\Code

# path to project binaries (optional), for example directory of Java bytecode
#sonar.binaries=binDir

# optional comma-separated list of paths to libraries. Only path to JAR file is supported.
#sonar.libraries=path/to/library/*.jar,path/to/specific/library/myLibrary.jar,parent/*/*.jar

# The value of the property must be the key of the language.
sonar.language=c++
sonar.exclusions=**/*.ipch, **/**/*.rc
sonar.cxx.cppcheck.path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Cppcheck\cppcheck.exe"
sonar.cxx.cppcheck.reportPath="D:\DiceInvaders\Code\cppcheck-reports\cppcheck.xml". 

# Additional parameters
#sonar.my.property=value
```

I do not get any error when running sonar-runner from cmd.

If i run manually the cppcheck.exe tool on my project I can find violations. Why don't the violations appear on sonar's page? 
Is there something else I should configure, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I'd also tried the advices from: http://sonar.15.x6.nabble.com/100-Rules-Compliance-with-C-project-td5008127.html (but I wasn't able to make it work)

Comment: sonar-runner will only utilise existing reports, not create them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to make it work by running the cppcheck tool independently before sonnar-runner, and placing the generated xml report in the bin folder of sonnar-runner.

In the sonar-project.properties file I've specified the xml directly:
sonar.cxx.cppcheck.reportPath=cppcheck-result-1.xml

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, which was caused by a whitespace after 'sonar.language=cs'. Be sure that there is a linebreak immediately after 'cxx'. Hope it works.

Answer (score -3):

The language key of the Sonar C++ Community plugin is not 'c++' but 'cxx'. See http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=185073817.

So you must replace 'sonar.language=c++' by 'sonar.language=cxx'

Comment: That doesn't work. I'm getting the error:  Caused by: You must install a plugin that supports the language 'cxx' which is not present when using c++ as language.